# Why is page table still kept in memory after closing the program?

Tags: memory, process, page-tables

I use the tool RamMap to monitor the memory usage on a windows 10 desktop. I find that the page table of a process still remained even when I closed the program. As shown in the snapshot, the program ansysedt.exe had two process. I closed the process with PID 15600, but the corresponding page table was kept in memory when the private meomory was cleaned. I wonder if this can use up my memory when the thousands of processes are created and then closed.

[Snapshot of RamMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRM4b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, apparently. Take a look at this question and answer:

https://superuser.com/questions/782855/why-does-my-page-table-take-up-so-much-memory

Some people would run out of physical memory and could only solve it by reboot, where the culprit was a program repeatedly starting and closing a process. In their case they pointed out two apps, in my case it happened with Docker Desktop in the background. The trace of Windows Performance Analyzer shows "Unknown" as culprit since they're not attached to any process anymore.

Unfortunately I'm not sure if there's any way of cleaning up these page tables save from a reboot of Windows...